# how to use JAX-WS webfault

Tags: java, web-services, jax-ws

I have written a webservice and tried to throw my custom exception but i am getting error please help me to solve it.

```
import javax.jws.WebService;
import javax.xml.ws.Endpoint;

@WebService(name = "WebService")
public class WebServiceTest {
    public String sayHello(String name) throws InvalidInputException {
        throw new InvalidInputException("I am testing", null);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        WebServiceTest server = new WebServiceTest();
        Endpoint endpoint = Endpoint.publish(
                "http://localhost:9191/webServiceTest", server);
    }
}


import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAttribute;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;

@XmlType(name = "InputMessageValidationFaultType")
public class FaultBean {

    @XmlAttribute
    protected String msg;

    public String getMsg() {
        return msg;
    }

    public void setMsg(String value) {
        this.msg = value;
    }

}


import javax.xml.ws.WebFault;

@WebFault(faultBean = "mytest.com.inc.FaultBean")
public class InvalidInputException extends Exception {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private FaultBean faultBean;

    public InvalidInputException() {
        super();
    }

    public InvalidInputException(String message, FaultBean faultBean,
            Throwable cause) {
        super(message, cause);
        this.faultBean = faultBean;
    }

    public InvalidInputException(String message, FaultBean faultBean) {
        super(message);
        this.faultBean = faultBean;
    }

    public FaultBean getFaultInfo() {
        return faultBean;
    }
}
```

**ERROR MESSAGE**
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.xml.ws.WebFault.messageName()Ljava/lang/String;
    at com.sun.xml.ws.model.RuntimeModeler.processExceptions(RuntimeModeler.java:1162)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.model.RuntimeModeler.processDocWrappedMethod(RuntimeModeler.java:898)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.model.RuntimeModeler.processMethod(RuntimeModeler.java:666)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.model.RuntimeModeler.processClass(RuntimeModeler.java:420)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.model.RuntimeModeler.buildRuntimeModel(RuntimeModeler.java:254)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.server.EndpointFactory.createSEIModel(EndpointFactory.java:338)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.server.EndpointFactory.createEndpoint(EndpointFactory.java:201)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.server.WSEndpoint.create(WSEndpoint.java:505)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.server.EndpointImpl.createEndpoint(EndpointImpl.java:257)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.server.EndpointImpl.publish(EndpointImpl.java:181)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.spi.ProviderImpl.createAndPublishEndpoint(ProviderImpl.java:123)
    at javax.xml.ws.Endpoint.publish(Endpoint.java:170)
    at mytest.com.inc.WebServiceTest.main(WebServiceTest.java:13)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Old question I know but I think the method names in your FaultBean class need to be getMessage and setMessage (as opposed to getMsg and setMsg) - see this excellent article:

http://io.typepad.com/eben_hewitt_on_java/2009/07/using-soap-faults-and-exceptions-in-java-jaxws-web-services.html

Answer (score 12):

Last time I saw this error, it was due by a missmatch of version of JAX-WS used (2.1.x and 2.2.x)
You are maybe compiling against the 2.1.x version but running against 2.2.x, or the other way round.

Keep in mind that the JDK 6 includes the 2.1.x version of JAX-WS, so you might have to use the endorsed library mechanism to force the usage of 2.2.x

Comment: I am using version **2.1.10** . can you tell me how do i get version **2.2.x** , how to use it as i will deploy this in tomcat and not as a simple java program. **Thanks A Lot**

Comment: as far as I know, the latest versions of the JAX-WS reference implementation are 2.1.7 and 2.2.3 and can be found there : http://jax-ws.java.net/